# My PC will boot but doesn't load bios or anything

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, power-supply, desktop-computer

I have an Acer X3995 PC and the other day I re-arranged some partitions and it stopped booting. When you press the "On" button the fans on the CPU and GPU spin up but nothing else happens. It might be the monitor but I don't think so because the light on the On button doesn't turn on and when plugged in it always turns on (not boots) immediately. I thought it might be the Motherboard's connection to the power supply but I opened the PC up and everything seems OK (I also unplugged and plugged in the cable that connects the motherboard to the power supply).

This might be a dupe of [956368](https://superuser.com/questions/956368/desktop-pc-monitor-wont-boot-mobo-doesnt-beep-but-hdd-and-fans-spin) but I'm getting No Signal from my monitor. If a picture of the inside would be helpful, I can edit it in